# An observation about variable memory addresses in C

Tags: c, memory-address

I have a question rather than a problem (witch maybe arises a memory question).. I've written this simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int multi(int x, int y);


int main(){
    int x;
    int y;
    printf("Enter the first number x: \n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("Enter the second number y: \n");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    int z=multi(x,y);
    printf("The Result of the multiplication is : %d\n",z,"\n");
    printf("The Memory adresse of x is : %d\n",&x);
    printf("The Memory adresse of y is : %d\n",&y);
    printf("The Memory adresse of z is : %d\n",&z);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

int multi(int x,int y){
    int c=x*y;
    printf("The Memory adresse of c is : %d\n",&c);
    return c;  
}
```

As you can see (if you develop in C), this program inputs 2 int variables, then multiplies them with the multi function:

after getting the result , it displays the location of each variable in the memory (`c`,`x`,`y` and `z`).

I've tested this simple example those are the results (in my case):

```
The Memory adresse of c is : 2293556  
The Result of the multiplication is : 12  
The Memory adresse of x is : 2293620  
The Memory adresse of y is : 2293616  
The Memory adresse of z is : 2293612
```

as you can see , the three variables `x`,`y`,`z` that are declared in the main function have closed memory adresses (22936xx) , the variable c that's declared in the multi function has a different adress (22935xx).

looking at the `x`,`y` and `z` variables, we can see that there's a difference of 4 bytes between each two variables (i.e : `&x-&y=4`, `&y-&z=4`).

my question is , why does the difference between every two variable equals 4?

Comment: Using `%d` to print pointer values is incorrect, unless you cast them to `(int)` first, and that's a bad idea. Instead, use `%p`.

Comment: thank you, I just tried to use pointers and it comes to a cast error :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x`, `y`, and `z`, are integer variables that will be created on the [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (but see below).  The `sizeof int` is 4 bytes, so that is how much space a compiler will allocate on the stack for those variables.  These variables are adjacent to one another, so they are 4 bytes apart.

You can read about how memory is allocated for local variables by looking for information on [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention).

In some cases (where you do not use the address-of operator), the compiler may optimize local variables into registers.

Answer (score 4):

In your situation the three variables were allocated in contiguous memory blocks. On x86 systems, `int` types are 32-bits wide, i.e. `sizeof(int) == 4`. So each variable is placed 4 bytes apart from the last.

Answer (score 2):

The size of a machine word on your machine is 4 bytes so, for speed of access by your program they offset each variable on a 4 byte boundary.

Comment: Alignment is important, but doesn't seem to be the issue here.

Comment: I would guess that if 3 char variables were declared, they would be on the same boundaries.

Comment: But the other amazing thing that the c variable in the other function is not on the same boundaries it's really a bit far from x y and z locations

Comment: I think it is on the same boundary.  What's different is that the stack frame is different and so you see that the function is quite far from the caller.

Answer (score 2):

Local variables are allocated on the "stack". Often the compiler will put them in sequential order since there's really no reason not to. An integer in C is 4 bytes. Therefore, it makes sense that `y` comes in 4 bytes after `x`, and `z` comes in 4 bytes after `y`.

Comment: but is this only in case of my machine or for every machine in the world? I can come to a conclusion that for a 64 bits machine, the for integers will be 8 bytes apart.

Comment: Most `int` types are 32 bits even in a 64-bit machine. (The "bitness" of a machine refers to the size of the memory-address register, not the size of an integer.) To get a 64-bit integer, use a `long` type.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are running on a 32-bit machine. The size of each `int` is 32 bits, and with 8 bits in a byte, the size of an `int` is 4 bytes. Each memory address corresponds to one byte, so there is a difference of 4 between the address of each local variable.

Comment: A 64-bit machine can still allocate 32 bits for an `int` type.